# The webbrowser if failing to load angular as shown in the images yet i have configured the app according to the book

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

[image: That's the webbrowser response][image: That is the browser response[![][1]][1]]

Am relatively new to webapp development but i don't understand why the browser can't load angular

Comment: Are you sure that the angular-route file exists in your project folder? Try using "/angular-route.js" in the script tag... The error is 404 (not found) for this file

Comment: Dear AlqbalRaj, it actully does exist as you can see in the file list on the right; i have also tried "/angular-route.js" but still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file in your folder is angular-route.min.js... The file you refer in the script tag is angular-route.js ...